# Android Add Application Class that not work

Tags: java, android

An issue add Application Class into the my application

Application Class:

```
 public class QmerceApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        ControlEventBus.getInstance().GetCommand(EventType.Application).SendEvent(EventType.Application, EventAction.ApplicationShutdown);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        ControlEventBus.getInstance().GetCommand(EventType.Application).SendEvent(EventType.Application, EventAction.ApplicationSetup);
    }
}
```

the manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.qmerce.client"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/qmerce_logo" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name="com.qmerce.client.QmerceApp">
        <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.Qmerceclient"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

now my issue i put break point and its getting there
have no idea what i doing wrong here...

Comment: You put breakpoint where? and it **is** or **isn't** getting there?

Comment: both onTerminate and onCreate

Comment: Testing on device? or on emulator?

Comment: On mobile device, `onTerminate()` will never be called. My guess is that by the time that your debugger connects to the process, `onCreate()` has already been called. If you really want to see if it is being called, add some logging in `onCreate()` which you can see in the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

hi i think you need to check about you packages , please have a look what package you are using, please be specified with them.

Comment: that class use package com.qmerce.client;